# Delete similar lines in an Emacs Org-Agenda file

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to clean up entrees in my `org-agenda` files. I have had many *duplicate* lines which I have removed using `delete-duplicate-lines`. However, I also have many *similar* lines which I would also like to delete, which are not identical. For example, in the two entries below:

```
John Doe is %d years old today (Birthday) <1968-08-21>

John Doe (Birthday) <1968-08-21>
```

I would like to find these similar lines and then keep the 1st entry but delete the second. I would obviously like to check each entry and select which line must be removed.

Comment: Define `similar`. You show two "similar" lines above, but do they have any similarity to any other pair of "similar" lines? If not, you'll just have to do them one pair at a time. E.g. search for `John Doe` or `(Birthday)` in this case, delete all the ones you don't want to keep and then repeat with the next pattern. Unless you have hundreds of these, that should not take too long. And if you have hundreds, just do the ones that appear in today's agenda: after a year, you'll be done :-)

Comment: You last suggestion is a good one and it did occur to me. Unfortunately, there are hundreds, the result of perhaps too much experimentation on my part with orgmode.